# Paging / Virtual Memory Translation

Tags: memory, memory-management

**Paging / Virtual Memory Translation**

Say we have an address space of 64 bytes, which equals 512 bits. 
With 16 byte pages, there are 4 pages in total within our address space. Each page has 128 bits available.

My textbook says because the virtual address
space of the process is 64 bytes, we need 6 bits total for our virtual address.

**Question 1:** *Why is the virtual address 6 bits? How do they come up with this number?*

**Question 2:** *And why does it split it into 16 byte pages? It could have split them into 8, 8 byte chunks?*

Comment: Unrelated to C++; you have the same issues with assembler code, or C, or Go, or Ocaml. Read http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/

Comment: That's what I'm reading. My question relates to the textbook, which is primarily made up of C code.

Comment: My point is that the `c++` tag is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the virtual address 6 bits? How do they come up with this number?

64 numbers require 6 bits to address

> And why does it split it into 16 byte pages? It could have split them into 8, 8 byte chunks?

Correct.  It is a decision

Comment: But shouldn't the virtual address be within 128 bits (Each page)? That's the size of the page it must fit in.